# Read 16-bit tif with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to read 16-bit color TIFs using opencv 2.4.3. The problem is that I can't get anything satisfying. All I get is a succession of black and grey lines.

[image: What I get, instead of a satellite image of Vancouver...]

I have tried different way to read the image :

```
cv::Mat cvimage = cv::imread(imageFile, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
cv::Mat cvimage = cv::imread(imageFile, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

cv::imshow("image", cvimage);
```

`type` of cvimage is `CV_16UC3`, as expected.

What is the correct way to read 16-bit images using opencv ?

Comment: Can you share the original image?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Unfortunatly I can't, it's a licenced image, and anyway it's 1.5 Gb.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cv::Mat cvimage = cv::imread(imageFile
                             , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
```

If this doesn't work, you can first convert it to `PNG` as OpenCV can read and even write 16bit PNG files correctly. You can convert your `TIFF` to `PNG` without loss.

```
cv::Mat cvimage = cv::imread(imageFile, -1);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but with the same result. I would rather not have my users convert their images. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @kishensurajP That was three years ago! Anyway if I remember correctly, I used GDAL to read the tifs and created a cv::Mat from that (I think you can reuse the buffer, no need for expensive copying). I hope it helps!